# Linking SDL with g++

Tags: c++, g++, sdl

I'm having some issues linking SDL with g++. I'm using Windows 10.

I have the SDL2.dll runtime binary file I got from www.libsdl.org in my lib folder in the project folder I'm working from.

However when I try to link SDL with the following command I get told that SDL2/SDL.h cannot be found:

```
C:\Users\******\Documents\*********>g++ main.cpp -o main -L/lib -lSDL2
In file included from main.cpp:2:
Window.h:1: SDL2/SDL.h: No such file or directory
```

Adding the -v tag gives me this message:

```
Reading specs from C:\cygnus\cygwin-b20\H-i586-cygwin32\bin\..\lib\gcc-lib\i586-cygwin32\egcs-2.91.57\specs
gcc version egcs-2.91.57 19980901 (egcs-1.1 release)
C:\cygnus\cygwin-b20\H-i586-cygwin32\bin\..\lib\gcc-lib\i586-cygwin32\egcs-2.91.57\cpp.exe -lang-c++ -v -iprefix C:\cygnus\cygwin-b20\H-i586-cygwin32\bin\..\lib/gcc-lib/i586-cygwin32\egcs-2.91.57\ -undef -D__GNUC__=2 -D__GNUG__=2 -D__cplusplus -D__GNUC_MINOR__=91 -Di386 -D_WIN32 -DWINNT -D_X86_=1 -D__STDC__=1 -D__stdcall=__attribute__((__stdcall__)) -D__cdecl=__attribute__((__cdecl__)) -D__declspec(x)=__attribute__((x)) -D__i386__ -D_WIN32 -D__WINNT__ -D_X86_=1 -D__STDC__=1 -D__stdcall=__attribute__((__stdcall__)) -D__cdecl=__attribute__((__cdecl__)) -D__declspec(x)=__attribute__((x)) -D__i386 -D__WINNT -Asystem(winnt) -Acpu(i386) -Amachine(i386) -D__EXCEPTIONS -remap -Acpu(i386) -Amachine(i386) -Di386 -D__i386 -D__i386__ -Di586 -Dpentium -D__i586 -D__i586__ -D__pentium -D__pentium__ -D__CYGWIN32__ -D__CYGWIN__ main.cpp C:\Users\shado\AppData\Local\Temp\cctsfB1Y.ii
GNU CPP version egcs-2.91.57 19980901 (egcs-1.1 release) (80386, BSD syntax)
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
C:\cygnus\cygwin-b20\H-i586-cygwin32\bin\..\lib\gcc-lib\i586-cygwin32\egcs-2.91.57\..\..\..\..\..\include\g++
C:\cygnus\cygwin-b20\H-i586-cygwin32\bin\..\lib\gcc-lib\i586-cygwin32\egcs-2.91.57\..\..\..\..\..\include
C:\cygnus\cygwin-b20\H-i586-cygwin32\bin\..\lib\gcc-lib\i586-cygwin32\egcs-2.91.57\..\..\..\..\i586-cygwin32\include
C:\cygnus\cygwin-b20\H-i586-cygwin32\bin\..\lib\gcc-lib\i586-cygwin32\egcs-2.91.57\include
\cygnus\cygwin-b20\H-i586-cygwin32\lib\gcc-lib\i586-cygwin32\egcs-2.91.57\..\..\..\..\..\include\g++
\cygnus\cygwin-b20\H-i586-cygwin32\lib\gcc-lib\i586-cygwin32\egcs-2.91.57\..\..\..\..\..\include
\cygnus\cygwin-b20\H-i586-cygwin32\lib\gcc-lib\i586-cygwin32\egcs-2.91.57\..\..\..\..\i586-cygwin32\include
\cygnus\cygwin-b20\H-i586-cygwin32\lib\gcc-lib\i586-cygwin32\egcs-2.91.57\include
End of search list.
```

And the file that gives me the error looks like this:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

class Window {
public:
    Window();
    ~Window();

    void initialize();

private:
    SDL_Window* window;

    int screenWidth;
    int screenHeight;
```

}

I apologize if I'm doing something blatantly wrong, I'm kind of new to g++ so I'm not 100% sure the best way to do things in it. Nevertheless, if anyone could help me out I would greatly appreciate it, thank you.

Comment: What OS are you using? Because it is my understanding that g++ is c/c++ compiler for Linux, but .dll files only work on Windows.

Comment: @Leo Oh I forgot to mention that, my apologies, I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: @Leo GCC is very widely used on Windows.

Comment: @NeilButterworth My mistake, since it stands for GNU Compiler Collection, I thought it was used only on Linux.

Comment: That error about SDL.h not being found is a compile error, *not* a link error. My *guess* would be that you simply have not told the compiler where to find the SDL includes (the `-I` option for gcc/g++).

Comment: @JesperJuhl I tried 
'g++ -g -Wall -I/lib main.cpp -o main'
and I still got the same error.

Comment: @Greg Salvesen why would you point the compiler at a lib directory in the search for header files?

Comment: @JesperJuhl Right, that makes sense that that wouldn't work. However when I tried `g++ -g -Wall -I/includes/SDL2-2.0.8/include main.cpp -o main` that also gave me the same error. That path includes the SDL.h file I'm looking for.

Comment: @GregSalvesen if you use relative path, you shouldn't have initial `/` after `-I`. And if your path is absolute, well it can't start with `/` on windows either.